# Keyframes for material animations don't appear!

Tags: materials, keyframes, graph-editor, timeline

[image: Ver 2.93]
I read some answers to the questions, but none of them worked.
https://developer.blender.org/T67359
https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/j0ayfx/where_are_texture_keyframes_located_at_blender_29/

I need to have the size keyframes appear in timeline or graph editor to adjust the animation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to have the size keyframes appear in the timeline or graphics editor to adjust the animation.

Comment: how would keyframing a texture brush work? Not sure to understand here... I think it makes no sense to keyframe a texture for the brush, but if you use it for a Displace modifier for example it will work... Please give more details...